# SciPy loadmat fails to load matlab structures with anonymous functions when simplify_cells=True

Tags: matlab, scipy, anonymous-function

Scipy.io.loadmat fails to load matlab structures from .mat files when they contain anonymous functions if the simplify_cells switch is set to True. I believe the reason is because loadmat registers anonymous functions as 0-dimensional mat_struct objects, but the loadmat pipeline requires mat_struct objects to have at least 1 dimension when using the simplify_cells switch. This description demonstrates the issue with a minimal code example and then indicates exactly which part of the code in scipy contains the bug.

The following were executed in Matlab:

```
exStruct = struct();             % in MATLAB!!
exStruct.anonymous = @(x) x;     % in MATLAB!!
save('exStruct.mat','exStruct')  % in MATLAB!!
```

Then, if you run the following block in python, an IndexError will be generated: "IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed"

```
import scipy.io as scio
fileName = 'exStruct.mat'
matStruct = scio.loadmat(fileName, simplify_cells=True)
```

In scipy.io.matlab._mio5.py: line 106, the function: _has_struct(elem) is as follows:

```
def _has_struct(elem):
    """Determine if elem is an array and if first array item is a struct."""
    return (isinstance(elem, np.ndarray) and (elem.size > 0) and
            isinstance(elem[0], mat_struct))
```

This function (_has_struct(elem)) causes the error when trying to load the anonymous function, because it is loaded as a 0-dimensional mat_struct.

Trying again with simplify_cells=False to load exStruct and show what the anonymous field looks like when loaded:

```
import numpy as np
matStruct = scio.loadmat(fileName, struct_as_record=False, squeeze_me=True)
exStruct = matStruct['exStruct']
print(exStruct.anonymous) # returns: <scipy.io.matlab._mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x000001B7FFFC3820>
print(isinstance(exStruct.anonymous, np.ndarray)) # True
print(exStruct.anonymous.size > 0) # True
print(exStruct.anonymous[0]) # IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed
```

For some reason, an anonymous function is returned as a mat_struct object with 0 dimensions. However, scipy.io.loadmat is only designed to handle mat_struct objects with at least 1 dimension. One solution to prevent an error is to include (elem.ndim>0) in the _has_struct(elem) function, however, I tried this and can't run the anonymous function after loading into python.

This issue was raised as an issue in the scipy github here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy.org/issues/516

^^ Above I just indicated that I added another boolean statement (elem.ndim>0), this prevents the error but I can't use the anonymous function in python.

Comment: A 0d array can be indexed as `exStruct.anonymous[()]` or `exStruct.anonymous.item()`. Whether you can do anything with the extracted object is a different matter.

Comment: `loadmat` creates numpy analogs for matlab matrices, cells, and struct.  It won't produce anything useful for classes or functions.

Comment: Thanks hpaulj. To be honest, the main reason for posting this is to document a bug. It took me a while to figure out why this wasn't working so hopefully other people that run into the same issues will find this and either know what to do or know why it isn't working as expected.

Comment: I'm not going to test any  of this since I don't have access to MATLAB (but do have Octave).  But out of curiosity, what happens when you use the `False`, and try one of my suggestions for extracting the function from the 0d array?  Can you use that anonymous function in any way?  Transferring data, numeric and string, across platforms is one thing, passing functions is a different matter.

Comment: `loadmat` has an example with `squeeze_me` and `item()`.  I wonder if that route has similar issues.  I've never had a need to use the the `simplify` parameter.  While I've answered an occasional numpy/matlab overlap questions, most of my work with MATLAB goes back a couple of decades.

Comment: No matter what I've tried I get the typeError: 'MatlabFunction' object is not callable. Thanks for your suggestions. It's just nice to use the simplify parameter to get dictionaries, and in it's current state, the scipy library fails for certain cases

Comment: I'm not surprised that a matlab function is not executable by python.